# mySQL not reading max_connections configuration

Tags: 16.04, mysql

I am trying to change the max_connections configuration for a mysql instance running on a Ubuntu 16.04 server. I have tried placing this configuration...

```
[mysqld]
max_connections = 400
```

...in the following files already: `/etc/my.cnf`, `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`, `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`, `/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf`.

I also added the following lines to `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld` and restarted apparmor:

```
/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/* rl,
/etc/mysql/conf.d/* rl,
```

Nevertheless, every time I restart the mysql service, I am getting a value of 214 from the following query:

```
show global variables like "max_connections";
```

The mysql version is `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.19, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper`.

What am I missing?

Comment: I changed mine in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`  and restarted mysql and it changed

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 16.04 the limits for the MySQL service are defined in the Systemd configuration file. To force MySQL read the value defined in your mysqld.cnf edit the service config:

```
sudo systemctl edit mysql.service
```

Add the following lines then save the file:

```
[Service]
LimitNOFILE=infinity
```

Restart the service:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart mysql.service
```

MySQL should use now the value defined in you config files.

Comment: I was looking for this and finally found after googling one day. Worked like charm on Ubuntu 16.04. Thanks!

Comment: This saved me eventually